# Spark, sum with step

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sum

I have a column with data in Spark. I need to generate a new column or array to sum up the numbers in a certain step.

Here's what I mean:

| A header |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |
| 6 |
| 7 |
| 8 |

For example, I need to get the sum of all the numbers in increments of 4. Then I expect the following:

| A header |
| --- |
| 10 |
| 26 |

Next happened, in the first line - 1+2+3+4, in the second 5+6+7+8 (summed all the values in increments of 4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the data that you have shared of sequential data, you may run the following query on your sparkSession eg

```scala
my_df.createOrReplaceTempView("my_data")

my_transformed_data = sparkSession.sql("<insert sql here>")
```

SQL to be used

```sql
    SELECT
        SUM(`A header`) as `A header`
    FROM
        my_data
    GROUP BY
         CAST((`A header`-1)/4 as INTEGER);
```

if the data or numbers you would like to sum are not sequential, you may use another incrementing field with the same logic or generate your own using `row_number` eg

```sql
    WITH my_data_groups AS (
        SELECT
            `A header`,
            CAST((row_number() OVER (ORDER BY 1)-1)/4 AS INTEGER) as grp
        FROM
            my_data
    )
    SELECT
        SUM(`A header`) as `A header`
    FROM
        my_data_groups
    GROUP BY
         grp;
```

***Results of db-fiddle below***
**Schema (SQLite v3.30)**

```
CREATE TABLE my_data (
  `A header` INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO my_data
  (`A header`)
VALUES
  ('1'),
  ('2'),
  ('3'),
  ('4'),
  ('5'),
  ('6'),
  ('7'),
  ('8'),
  ('9'),
  ('10'),
  ('11'),
  ('12'),
  ('13')
  ;
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT
    SUM(`A header`) as `A header`
FROM
    my_data
GROUP BY
     CAST((`A header`-1)/4 as INTEGER);
```

| A header |
| --- |
| 10 |
| 26 |
| 42 |
| 13 |

---

**Query #2**

```
WITH my_data_groups AS (
    SELECT
        `A header`,
        CAST((row_number() OVER ()-1)/4 AS INTEGER) as grp
    FROM
        my_data
)
SELECT
    SUM(`A header`) as `A header`
FROM
    my_data_groups
GROUP BY
     grp;
```

| A header |
| --- |
| 10 |
| 26 |
| 42 |
| 13 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wBhsa3VURqez72DcknjdyY/0)

Comment: Just an observation @ggordon. When I tried this with numbers ranging from 1 to 12,it yielded different result set .Instead of 26 for the second group it gives 35(5,6,7,8,9 will be grouped under 1).I think this requires a tweak. Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @linusRian i've updated the answer with a modification and db-fiddle to assist replication